# 'Multiplication' of Spinors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, spinors

I am struggling to understand what is meant when spin eigenstates are 'multiplied' together. For example, Brandsen and Joachain's Quantum Mechanics says that there are four spin eigenfunctions for a two particle system:

$$ \alpha(1)\alpha(2), \alpha(1)\beta(2), \beta(1)\alpha(2), \beta(1)\beta(2)$$

Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the simultaneous eigenfunctions of the single-particle spin operators $S^2$ and $S_z$.

If a spinor can be represented by $[a \space b]^T$, what does it mean to 'multiply' two spinors together?

And further, how should I then try to do something simple like take the magnitude squared of such a state? I.e.:

$$ \alpha^*(1)\alpha^*(2)\alpha(1)\alpha(2) $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He means the tensor product. In quantum mechanics, when one handles two systems in different Hilbert spaces, $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H}_2$, the joint state that considers the two systems lives in $\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$. So, if you have two spin states $|\alpha(1)\rangle\in\mathcal{H}_1$ and $|\alpha(2)\rangle\in\mathcal{H}_2$ ,the state that describes the two states will be
$$|\alpha(1)\rangle\otimes|\alpha(2)\rangle, \:\:\text{usually denoted by} \:\:|\alpha(1)\alpha(2)\rangle.$$

Regarding the probability amplitude, that would be given by

$$\langle\alpha(1)\alpha(2)|\alpha(1)\alpha(2)\rangle = \langle\alpha(1)|\alpha(1)\rangle\langle\alpha(2)|\alpha(2)\rangle,$$

although the equation above is only valid for separable states.